# Java mongodb как работать с элементами типа Map?

Tags: java, mongodb

В коллекцию в mongo сохраняется `Map<String,Integer> activity`. В бд обьект хранится в виде

```
"activity" : {
    "20160409" : 7,
    "20160404" : 63,
    "20160401" : 16,
    "20160408" : 84,
    "20160405" : 54
}
```

Как в Java можно при создании запроса к бд сделать forEach этой мапы и пройтись по ее значениям ? То есть допустим нужно узнать есть ли в мапе дата с кол-вом посищений более 100.

Или другой пример когда в значение в map хранится более сложный обьект у которого есть много полей, и нужно сделать тоже самое. Это как в java сделать values() к мапе.

Важно это делать в самой монге! Т.е. не выгружая всю коллекцию из могни и потом средствами java перебирать. Я знаю что можно обратится к элементу мапы типа так activity.20160409, но как пройтись по всем значениям пока что то не находил. Буду признателен тому кто подскажет)